# Is there a connection between the definitions of one- and two-particle reduced density matrices?

Tags: chemistry, many-body-systems

In quantum chemistry, there are concepts about one-particle reduced density matrix (1-RDM) and similarly, the two-particle reduced density matrix (2-RDM).
Generally, for an $n$ particle wavefunction $|\Psi\rangle$ and the corresponding density matrix is ${}^nD=|\Psi\rangle\langle\Psi|$. Then there are two definitions of the 1-RDM and 2-RDM. The first is:
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
{}^1D= \begin{pmatrix}
1 \\
n
\end{pmatrix} tr_{2,3,\cdots,n} {}^nD,
\end{equation}
in which will resulting $C_n^1=n$ density matrix. Another method is to define the element of 1-RDM as:
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
{}^1D_{ij} = \langle \Psi|a_i^{\dagger} a_j|\Psi\rangle,
\end{equation}
in which $i$ and $j$ run over  $1$ to $n$ and the matrix will be a $n\times n$ one. Is there any connection or difference between the two representations?

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by $a^{\dagger}_{i}$ and $a_{j}$? Are they ladder operators?

Comment: There are creation and annihilation operators.

Comment: You'll find more people that know what you're talking about here: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you are interested in moving the question to Matter Modeling, I'm a mod there and we would be open to having it migrated. I can contact the mods here to have it moved.

Comment: OK. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately you did not tag @Tyberius (or me) on that comment, so we didn't see it.